# [docker-py SDK]: docker service update How to pass "--config-rm" and --config-add options

Tags: python, docker, docker-swarm, dockerpy

I am fighting with automating smth with docker SDK for python.
All went well until I need to run the following command:

```
    docker service update --config-rm "$OLD_CONFIG"\
     --config-add source="$NEW_CONFIG",target=/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/config.cfg,mode=0440\
     busybox_busybox
```

There is a code reference - [SDK services](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html)

Here is my code:

```
...
client = docker.DockerClient(docker_server)
client.configs.create(name=new_config, data=data) - success
svc = client.services.get("busybox_busybox") - success
svc.update(image="nginx)
```

however, I can't understand how to pass these options "--config-rm abc" and "--config-add"

PS: I was able to create an external config but unable to update service by removing the old one and attaching the one I have created just a line ago